# Making the tip of a right chevron font-awesome icon touch end of div

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Using a font-awesome chevron icon or right arrow icon from any icon library how can I make it so the point of the icon touches the edge of the div that it is in perfectly.

Please see the following code example and notice how even though I am doing text-align: right; It does not perfectly touch the edge of the sidebar. I believe this is because the icon has a small amount of spacing to the right of it. Is there anyway I can gain control of this little bit of spacing?

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 00 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: right;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="sidebar">
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It seems the SVG of the icon has an offset to the right of 1px. You should, indeed, compensate that with CSS, with either `position:relative; right:-1px;`, or `margin-right:1px;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for you! 
Basically, create a class `.fa-chevron-right` and give it `margin-right: -2px;`

You can increase/decrease -2px to get the spacing to your liking!

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 00 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: right;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #000;
}
.fa-chevron-right {
  margin-right: -2px; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="sidebar">
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      
    </div>
    </div>
```